# strange outline when making shapes in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

[image]

i have issues with the rectangle and elipse tool where everytime i draw something i get these really odd edges around the shape. this is in a new document and i was having this issue on the document i work on also. i dont understand what i have done for it to work like this.

Comment: Is there by any change a dashed boarder around the shapes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With one of the shapes selected, open the stroke/fill palette by clicking on the tool bar, Object, Stroke/Fill or pressing Shift_Control_F or finding it in the panel to the right side on a default screen.

Within the panel, select the Stroke Paint tab to set the desired color. Select Stroke Style and note the Dashes field under the width box. It appears that your settings are of one of the many dashes available within Inkscape. Scroll up in the drop-down list to select a solid line, or alternatively, use the X in Stroke Paint tab to remove the stroke.